# Is there some more elegant way to assign a specific value to a variable in case of an error?

Tags: python

In this case, we assign a variable a value that the class method returns. However, in case of a potential error, the script execution will end with an exception, or the value `None` will be assigned

```
import platform
system = platform.system()
```

Often we can use such a construction to assign a certain value in case of an exception:

```
try: info['platform']=platform.system()
except: info['platform']="NA"
```

The question is whether it is possible to do such processing in one line, and what methods exist for handling such exceptions in general.

Comment: The [idea of a `try` expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0463/) was rejected years ago.

Comment: (`platform.system` seems like a weird example, though, as I'm not aware of any circumstances in which it would raise an exception.)

Comment: `info['platform'] = platform.system() or "NA"`, as the function will return an empty string in the absence of an actual platform to return.